# Updating the view for an Othello game

Tags: java, android, user-interface, refresh

I'm developing a Reversi game on Android, and look for an efficient way to refresh the view after each move. I know I can't do it on the main thread, so I thought about AsyncTask.

Glad to hear any ideas ;)

Okay, I thought the code is not necessary in this case, but here we go:

a) my game view class:

```
    public class GameView extends SurfaceView{

SurfaceHolder holder;
ViewRefreshThread vrt;
Game game;
Drawer drawer;
int player;

public GameView (Context context)
{
    super(context);
    holder = getHolder();
    vrt = new ViewRefreshThread (this);
    game = new Game();
    drawer = new Drawer(context, game);
    player = GameBoard.BLACK;

    holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback(){

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                int width, int height) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(vrt.isNew == true)
            {
                vrt.isNew = false;
                vrt.start();
            }
            else vrt.run = true;


        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            vrt.run = false; 
        }   
    });
    //AsyncUpdate u = new AsyncUpdate();
    //u.execute(this);

}

public void pause()
{
    vrt.run = false;
}

public void resume()
{
    vrt.run = true;
}

/** 
 * Function recalculating the coordinates of the pressed screen location to the game board positon
 * @param float touchX - x coordinate in pixels of the pressed location
 * @param float touchY - y coordinate in pixels of the pressed location
 * @return int[] result - array of the calculated coordinates
 */

public int[] coordsToField (float touchX, float touchY)
{
    int chunk = this.getWidth()/8;
    int x, y;
    x = y = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if(chunk*(i+1) > touchX)
        {
            x = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        if(chunk*(j+1) > touchY)
        {
            y = j;
            break;
        }
    }
    int[] result = {x, y};
    return result;
}



@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    boolean move = false;


    int[] arr = coordsToField (event.getX(), event.getY());
    Field f = new Field (arr[0], arr[1]);
    /*player's move */
    if(!game.isAvailable(game.game_board, f))
    {
        return false;
    }
    move = game.move(f, game.game_board, game.getActive_player());
    game.changePlayer();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    /*computer's move */
    int depth = 0;
    f = game.alg.findBestMove(game.game_board, depth, game.getActive_player());
    if (f!=null)
    {
        game.move(f, game.game_board, game.getActive_player());
    }
    game.changePlayer();


    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public int changePlayer (int player)
{
    return  player == GameBoard.BLACK ? GameBoard.WHITE : GameBoard.BLACK;
}
```

}

B) my refreshing thread:

```
public class ViewRefreshThread extends Thread
{
GameView gview;
private final static int FPS = 100;
protected boolean run = true;
protected boolean isNew = true;

public ViewRefreshThread(GameView gview) {
    this.gview = gview;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    long ticksPS = 1000 / FPS;
    long startTime;
    long sleepTime;

    while (true) {
        if (!run) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100L);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
            }
            continue;
        }
        Canvas c = null;
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            c = gview.getHolder().lockCanvas();
            synchronized (gview.getHolder()) {
                gview.drawer.draw(c);
            }
        }
        finally {
            if (c != null) {
                gview.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                gview.postInvalidate();
            }
        }
        sleepTime = ticksPS - (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
        try {
            if (sleepTime > 0)
                sleep(sleepTime);
            else
                sleep(10);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating the view for a Reversi game](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451985/updating-the-view-for-a-reversi-game)

Comment: the question was on hold, I deleted it already. I still wait for the answer ;)